# Check if any value in any 2 arrays with different dimension is same in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, intersect

I have 2 arrays -

```
$arr1 =

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sender_email] => test1@test.com
            [to_email] => test@test.com
            [description] => 5390BF675E1464F32202B
            [created_at] => 2020-01-21 04:50:21
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 30
            [sender_email] => abcd@gmail.com
            [to_email] => test@test.com
            [description] => 729237A55E2EDCB80B18F
            [created_at] => 2020-01-27 12:51:34
            [status] => 1
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [sender_email] => abc@gmail.com
            [to_email] => test@test.com
            [description] => 729237A55E2EDCB80B18F
            [created_at] => 2020-01-27 12:51:34
            [status] => 1
        )

)

$arr2 =
Array
(
    [0] => test1@test.com
    [1] =>  abb@abb.com
    [2] =>  abc@gmail.com
)
```

I am trying to find the matching values from $arr2 which also exist in $arr1.

I tried with

```
if(array_intersect($arr2, $arr1)) {
            die('wrong');
        }
```

But it show error like -

```
 Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

I think due to difference in structure. How can this be achieved? It will be really helpful if I can get all matching values in one array. The column name will always be same but I request to not make that an inclusion in the code.

Comment: You are having error with `array_intersect()` because of your array is not valid. Simple ways to find matches `array_intersect()` or `array_intersect_assoc()` or `array_intersect_key()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$matches = []; // array which will contains matches
foreach($arr1 as &$el){ // loop through the elements
   if(array_intersect($arr2,$el)) array_push($matches, $el); //and if there is at least one elements as intersect of the two arrays, add it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that code. But I request if you can make it such that I do not require to add column names in the function. I wanted to be dynamic

Comment: oh sorry, you mean that the $arr2 values should be searched in all the fields of the elements in $arr1? @Gagan

Comment: Yes, That would be great. Thanks

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive function loops through all elements in every depth and searches for the elements in the `$needle`. It `returns an array with all matched values`:

```
function array_search_recursive( $needle, $haystack, $strict = false, &$matches = array() )  {
  foreach( $haystack as $value )  {
    if( is_array( $value ) )  {
      array_search_recursive( $needle, $value, $strict, $matches );
    } else {
      if( in_array( $value, $needle, $strict ) ) {
        $matches[] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
  return $matches;
}

// Parameters
// $needle: The array containing the searched values
// $haystack: The array to search in
// $strict: If it is set to true, it will also perform a strict type comparison
// $matches: Is only needed for recursion
```

Usage:

```
$haystack = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'email' => 'test@mail.de'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'email' => 'mymail@web.de'
  ),
);

$needle = array( 'mymail@web.de', 1, 'lala@web.de' );

$matches = array_search_recursive( $needle, $haystack );
```

The `value of $matches`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => mymail@web.de
)
```

Comment: Array
(
) It gave blank array in return

Comment: You use it with the same arrays as in your question?

Comment: Yes, those are variable I getting and I just tried your code.

Comment: This code works as expected, Thanks. But I can only approve one answer, so approved the one which has lesser code. But Thanks